# Grade student as number of array scores

Tags: javascript

Assume that you have the ready sorted array

Is it a good solution?

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/JH5YjzTwaIlon27CdguU?p=preview) OR:

```
<script>
    var score = [10, 20, 20, 20, 40, 50, 60, 60, 60, 60, 70, 80, 80, 90]
    var j = 0;
    var k = 0;

    for( i in  score ){
        var grade = '';

        if( i== 0 || score[i] > score[i - 1] ){
            grade = j = j+1+k;
            k = 0;
        }else{
            k++;
            grade = j;
        }

        document.write( 'Grade: ' + ( grade ) +'<br>');
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: What is the objective of this code?  What are you trying to accomplish?  For starters, you should never iterate an array with `for( i in  score )` as that iterates properties, not just array elements which can include things other than array elements.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00 : thanks for the comment. I would like to grade students as number(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6...) of array scores.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 1):

The value your looking for is more like a position rather then a grade. 
Just add...

```
var position   = 0; 
var last_grade = 0;
```

outside the for loop. then add a comparison before the document.write... statement like so.

```
if (grade>last_grade) position++;
document.write( 'Grade: ' + ( position ) +'<br>');
last_grade=grade;
```

That should give you the following result...

```
Grade: 1<br>
Grade: 2<br>
Grade: 2<br>
Grade: 2<br>
Grade: 3<br>
Grade: 4<br>
Grade: 5<br>
Grade: 5<br>
Grade: 5<br>
Grade: 5<br>
Grade: 6<br>
Grade: 7<br>
Grade: 7<br>
Grade: 8<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

By reading your code it seems that you want to have grades between 0 and 15. Thus I do not understand why your are checking the previous entry in the array (score[i] > score[i - 1]), I think it can be converted to something more simpler and readable.

This is a proposal:

```
<script>
  var score = [10, 20, 20, 20, 40, 50, 60, 60, 60, 60, 70, 80, 80, 90];
  score.forEach(function(item) {
    document.write('Grade: ' + (Math.round(item/100*15)) + '<br>');
  });
</script>
```

Result:

```
Grade: 2
Grade: 3
Grade: 3
Grade: 3
Grade: 6
Grade: 8
Grade: 9
Grade: 9
Grade: 9
Grade: 9
Grade: 11
Grade: 12
Grade: 12
Grade: 14
```

If needed, you can easily change the Maths to suits your need.

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  While alternative coding solutions are good, we prefer to have more review in our answers.  What was wrong with the original code?  Why is this code better?  How do you know that it returns the same result?  It's better to help people learn how to code than to just give them code.

Comment: Hi @ponsfrilus: thanks for the answer but look at the result, 2,3,3,3,6,8...
it doesn't work hik hik

Comment: That's why I said that you can adjust the Maths. Anyway how can you give same score different grade ? That's absurd... @RadyArchuleta

Answer (score 0):

Your OP and your plunkr differ, in that the plunkr has the scores sorted from highest to lowest.  Since that makes more sense to me, I'll assume that is correct.

I'd suggest a rewrite where you map each raw score to its rank, which is the heart of what you are doing:

```
var scores = [90, 80, 80, 70, 60, 60, 60, 60, 50, 40, 20, 20, 20, 10];
var grades = scores.map(x => scores.indexOf(x) + 1);
```

Which will produce:

```
[1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9, 10, 11, 11, 11, 14]
```

What this is saying is that each person's rank is equal to index, within the raw scores, of the *first* occurrence of their raw score.

Here's [an updated plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/1x8ZyRbgyWxauBtJKCUe?p=preview)

### UPDATE

To answer your question in the comments you can do something like (this is untested, but should work):

```
objArr.sort((a,b) => b.projection - a.projection)
      .map(x => {
        var grade = objArray.findIndex(y => y.projection == x.projection) + 1);
        return Object.assign(x, {grade});
      });
```

Comment: Very nice Jonah...

Comment: what about doing it over object with this algorithm [{"Id":571,"UserId":"auth0|56e7ea6f2698a49f50589a3f","Nickname":"sophorn","Entry":1,"Bets":59,"Payout":0,"projection":15479,"grade":1},"Id":470,"UserId":"auth0|567816fc203da0ab0da65bcf","Nickname":"khen","Entry":1,"Bets":8,"Payout":0,"projection":10859,"grade":2},{"Id":606,"UserId":"auth0|56e8e05f2698a49f5058b40d","Nickname":"rinrady","Entry":1,"Bets":1,"Payout":0,"projection":10229,"grade":3}]. 

I would like to give the player position by field "projection", can you help?

Comment: not sure i understand, can you clarify?

Comment: To grade player with below object by "projection" field

[{"Id":571,"UserId":"auth0|56e7ea6f2698a49f50589a3f","Nickname":"sophorn","Entry‌​":1,"Bets":59,"Payout":0,"projection":15479,"grade":1},"Id":470,"UserId":"auth0|5‌​67816fc203da0ab0da65bcf","Nickname":"khen","Entry":1,"Bets":8,"Payout":0,"project‌​ion":10859,"grade":2},{"Id":606,"UserId":"auth0|56e8e05f2698a49f5058b40d","Nickna‌​me":"rinrady","Entry":1,"Bets":1,"Payout":0,"projection":10229,"grade":3}]

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution.

Comment: Yeah, but I made a little change to that and  this is the link to that  https://plnkr.co/edit/mlJaGXdazcfdUUju1CC5?p=preview

Comment: Is that not what you wanted?  It seems analogous to the plunkr in your OP....